# SQL getting records for the last quarter with 30 days grace period

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I want to find the company records which has not done the filing for the last quarter, but i want to give grace period of 30 days. As in till Oct 30 2018, the company_seq should not be fetched. I am not able to do the grace period part. Can someone please help me?

And more thing to consider is, if the filing is not done for the previous quarter i.e. quarter 2, then the company sequence should be fetched

Sample Data

```
Company_seq YEAR    QUARTER
1           2018    2
1           2018    3
2            2018   2
2           2018    1
3          2018 1

Company_SEQ COMPANY_NAME    
1           Company 1   
2          Company2 
3           Company3    



SELECT * FROM COMPANY 
WHERE company_seq NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT company_seq 
        FROM Filing F
        WHERE YEAR = (SELECT TO_CHAR(add_months(sysdate,-3),'YYYY') from dual)
        AND quarter=(SELECT TO_CHAR(add_months(sysdate,-3),'Q') from dual)
```

Expected Query output:

```
3, Company3
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle Database ? Both are different RDBMS

Comment: ORACLE database

Comment: even if you are able to provide some inputs using MYSQL, i can atleast know the logic, so i can try something

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output in tabular format .

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket from your sub-query.

Comment: I am missing the whole logic Paul.. And about the bracket, i  took this out from some huge query so ignore bracket

Comment: Added sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below query and it did work

```
SELECT * FROM Temp_Company_Neha 
WHERE company_seq NOT IN( 
SELECT DISTINCT company_seq     FROM Temp_Neha dehp 
              WHERE YEAR = (SELECT TO_CHAR(add_months(sysdate,-3),'YYYY') from dual)
              AND quarter=(SELECT TO_CHAR(add_months(sysdate - 30,-3),'Q') from dual));
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking something like this:

```
select c.company_seq
from company c
group by c.company_seq
having add_months(max(add_months(to_date(year || '0101', 'YYYYMMDD'), 3 * c.quarter)), 1) < sysdate
```

The inner `add_months()` converts the year/quarter to the start of the *next* quarter.  The outer `add_months()` is the grace period.